# Higher Resolution Viewport Render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, opengl

I'm trying to render a black/white wireframe image of my scene and have perfected how I'd like it to look in the shading viewport, but I can't figure out how to save out that viewport at high resolution. The open GL render is very low-res. How can I make those lines as sharp as in the shader, or save out the shader image full res?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Viewport render uses the image size settings of the current renderer.

Change the resolution here:

[image]

And render using:

[image]

Comment: 1920x1080 at 100% are my current settings for the render shown above

Comment: Render view not zoomed?